# How to add Objective-C Bridging Header entry?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods, header-files

I have a Swift project and have add a cocoapod, which is written in Objective-C. It has header and implementation files. From what I understand, to use/import these files into my Swift files, I need to add a bridging file.

I found this site describing how to do this manually, since the Objective-C files are already part of my project (from the cocoapod).

http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/

1.) Navigate to your project build settings and find the “Swift Compiler – Code Generation” section.  You may find it faster to type in “Swift Compiler” into the search box to narrow down the results.

2.) Next to “Objective-C Bridging Header” you will need to add the name/path of your header file.  If your file resides in your project’s root folder simply put the name of the header file there.

I don't have a `Objective-C Bridging Header` in that section and it doesn't appear you can add new entries there.

[image]

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1. Anyone have some idea how this should be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you looked at the correct Build Settings section, search with the keyword **Swift compiler - General** in the search field as describe below and then you can find it.

[image]

Comment: How do I include two file references here? I have them on 2 lines but it keeps combining them into file file path, which fails because that path isn't found.

Comment: How do you make that work when the two files are part of the same Objective-C project?

Comment: Include header of those files in the objective C bridging header

Comment: No, you only need one bridging header that will contain the headers of Objective C code that you want to use in Swift.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the header file first. It is a regular Objective-C header file and should be named `<Your app or framework name>-Bridging-Header.h`. For any Objective-C headers you want Swift to know about add an import statement to the newly created header file. Then follow your previous steps.
There is also a hidden header that gets created for you called `<Your app or framework name>-Swift.h`. If you need to access any Swift classes from an Objective-C file import this header.