# UnitTest in swift | IOS Storyboard | Failed to cast viewcontroller class defined in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing, storyboard

So I am trying to write down some test cases for one of my controller class,

1. My viewcontroller is defined in objective c.
2. I am writing test cases in swift.
3. I have included my viewcontroller class in both my main target and my test target.
4. I have also added the storybaord in both test and main target.

In my test I am trying to load the view controller from story board, below is the code (this code is working fine in my normal project from swift class)

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.init(for: self.classForCoder))
    let viewController:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController")
    print(viewController.classForCoder)
    print(type(of: viewController))
    let _ = viewController.view
    controller = viewController as! LoginViewController
```

print output

```
LoginView Controller 

__ABT_LoginViewController
```

Last line of my code is getting failedi.e

`controller = viewController as! LoginViewController`

error I am getting below

`Could not cast value of type '__ABT_LoginViewController' (0x600000053b30) to 'LoginViewController' (0x11e88de30).`

Need your help guys

**Updated**
So above issue resolved after following the answer by @dashandrest, Now I am facing new issue, I have created a TestAppdelegate file for test cases, in my TestAppDelegate class I have this statement import "App-swift.h now after compiling the whole code it is giving an error inside App-swift.h file mentioning cannot import module AppName, My main target module name is AppName whereas test target module name is AppNameTest,

`#import "App-swift.h"`
Now I am getting compiling error inside App-swift.h file.

```
#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
@import ObjectiveC; 
@import AppName; ///this line generate compile errror, module AppName not found 
@import XCTest;
#endif
```

## **Updated**

So there were multiple issues in my app which I resolved, definitely @DashAndRest input help me in identifying those, below are the things I correct in order to make things work.

1. Remove all code files from test target except the test cases.
2. Make sure that I have separate Module name for my main target and test target.
3. Make sure that My Pods file does have installing the libraries for my test target also.
4. Write test cases in Swift for the safe side so that I don't need to include Appname-swift.h in test cases.
5. Use @testable import AppModuleName (as suggested by @DashAndRest)

Comment: Check the solution now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not required:

> 3 I have included my viewcontroller class in both my main target and my test target.
>   4 I have also added the storybaord in both test and main target.

Try unchecking Test target for both view controller and storyboard.
And then in your test file just include main target as:

```
@testable import Your-Main-Target-Name
```

### Update

Still `App-swift.h` is confusing.

But if you want to test `LoginViewController`, here is the solution:

Add [Bridging Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468397/how-to-add-objective-c-bridging-header-entry) to your main **AppName** target and import all the objective-c classes to it, like:

```
#ifndef AppName_Bridging_Header_h
#define AppName_Bridging_Header_h

#import "LoginViewController.h"

#endif
```

After this, your `LoginViewController` class will be available for all other swift classes to use, including test target.

Add new file like `LoginVCTests.swift` in test target and add following code to it-

```
import XCTest
@testable import AppName

class LoginVCTests: XCTestCase {
  func testSomeLogic() { 
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController:UIViewController =     storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    print(viewController.classForCoder)
    print(type(of: viewController))
    let _ = viewController.view
    //test on viewController
  }
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: You rock man, but this works fine in case of a LoginViewController, but it does not work in case of my manager class for login view controller i.e LoginDataManager, it gives me compile time error of not finding the LoginDataManager class in my unit test class, as I remove LoginDataManager also from test target.

Comment: can you place code for your `LoginDataManager`? just structure; every class that is inside main target should be available for test target after importing testable!

Comment: So this is kinda weird, after clean/build that LoginDataManager issue gone and now it is showing new issue, I have created a TestAppdelegate file for test cases, in my TestAppDelegate class I have this statement `import "App-swift.h` now after compiling the whole code it is giving an error inside App-swift.h file mentioning cannot import module `AppName`, My main target module name is `AppName` whereas test target module name is `AppNameTest,`.

Comment: And what is that?

Comment: Just added more detail in my above comment, really appreciate all your help :)

Comment: ```#if defined(__has_feature) && __has_feature(modules)
@import ObjectiveC;
@import AppName; ///this line generate compile errror ; module AppName not found
@import XCTest;
#endif
```

Comment: please edit your question instead of comments, it's confusing; m not getting this code