# In Swift Unit Tests I'm getting a class cast error between App and Unit Test Targets

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift3, xcode8

In an iOS 10, Swift 3 Application I'm trying to test a ViewController using NotificationCenter.

At my ViewController initialization I query a provider for data and receive a synchronous response. The provider then try to refresh the data using a asynchronous call to web and, if it was changed, send a notification that will be catched by the ViewController. Here is a piece of my ViewController initialization:

```
class func instantiateWithId(_ id: String, provider: DataProvider) -> MyViewController {

   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle(for:MyViewController.self));
   let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerId") as! MyViewController;

   controller.dataProvider = provider;
   controller.objectId = id;
   controller.object = controller.dataProvider!.getObject(id: id, completion: controller.refreshObject);

   return controller; 
}
```

After initialization I register the notification observer that is working fine:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.catchNotification), name: NotificationName, object: nil);
```

Here is the function that process the notification in the ViewController. It is working fine:

```
func catchNotification(notification: NSNotification) -> Void {

   guard (notification.name == NotificationName) else {return;}
   let info = notification.userInfo as! [String: Any];
   if info.count > 0 {

       guard (info[objectId] != nil) else {return;}
       if let value = info[objectId] as! MyCustomStruct? {
           self.refreshData(updated: value);
       }
    }
}
```

In the Provider, as soon I receive the asynchronous response from web, I send the notification with the new data in userInfo:

```
var dict = Dictionary<String, myCustomStruct>();
dict.updateValue(newData, forKey: newData.objectId);

let msg = Notification(name: NotificationName, object: nil, userInfo: dict)
NotificationCenter.default.post(msg);
```

All the codes above are working fine, But in my Unit Test I get an error when the notification is catched by my ViewController saying that myCustomStruct for the UnitTest Target can not be casted to myCustomStruct in Application Target:

```
Could not cast value of type ‘ApplicationUnitTests.MyCustomStruct’ (0x1161fa828) to ‘Application. myCustomStruct' (0x1057fd6d0).
```

I already checked and the CustomStruct is available to the two targets.

Here is my test:

```
func testViewControllerInitialization() {
   let fixture = MockDataProvider();
   let sutId = fixture.testId;
   let sut = MyViewController.instantiateWithId(sutId, provider: fixture)

   _ = sut.view;
   XCTAssertNotNil(sut, "SUT not initialized");
   XCTAssertNotNil(sut.object, "Object Not Loaded!");
   XCTAssertEqual(sutId, sut.object!.objectId, "Differente ObjectId expected!");

   let newValue = "changed";
   var nextFixture = fixture.getObject(objectId: sutId, completion: {(result) in return;});
   nextFixture.name = newValue;

   fixture.refreshObject(newData: nextFixture); <- This function send the notification
   sleep(1);
   XCTAssertEqual(newValue, sut.object!.name);
}
```

Comment: The error completely describes the problem: app expects `Application.myCustomStruct` and you're sending `ApplicationUnitTests.MyCustomStruct`. Can't you use `Application.myCustomStruct` in tests?

Comment: The point is: I do not have an ApplicationUnitTests.MyCustomStructs. I just have Application.myCustomStruct. As I understand, the ApplicationUnitTests target would import all Application Target classes. if I need to duplicate the classes in the Test Target the whole idea of unit test lost sense.

Comment: Application files (and thus their included classes and other Types) are not automatically imported to unit test targets. When you create a new file you specify what targets you want it to be part of. If you do not add your unit test target then, you can add it later from the inspector (select the file, open the inspector and tick your test target).

Comment: I'm aware of that. In the case related, all files: structs, viewcontrollers, providers, even the storyboard are included in the test target.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a long research without any response I 'found' a solution for my problem. Using information of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138661/unittest-in-swift-ios-storyboard-failed-to-cast-viewcontroller-class-defined) stackoverflow post I tryed some monkey business things and the error is gone.

Actually, what solve the problem was disabling my Main Storyboard for the UnitTest Target. I enabled it because of the `instantiateWithId` method listed in the question. As per my understand, it would be necessary to link it to test target to instantiate it in the code used by the Test Target But for some reason this were a wrong thing to do.

Now it is working and I can continue with my Swift TDD. But If someone could explian me why this is the correct configuration for test I promisse give your name for my next child.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Actually, I can not continue with TDD because now my code does not find the Main Storyboard because it is not linked to the UnitTestTarget. Like I thought it could happen and that's the reason I linked it since the beginning.