# Can't access oc category methods in Swift subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a swift subclass of UIView, and an objective-c category for UIView. 
Why can't I access the category methods inside the subclass? The category is added to the bridging file...

Comment: It _definitly_ is possible to use ObjC-Categories in Swift. You should show us the important parts of your code, maybe there is a typo or so.

Comment: Please verify you have done the steps mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468397/how-to-add-objective-c-bridging-header-entry?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Have you added flags like -Objc, -all_load etc.?